# Subversion Working Copy on Network Share don't show Subversion Status

Tags: svn

I am very new to the Subversion system but based on my experience on TFS and CVS, I belive I can have the my working copy on a network and it wroks as well.

But only problem I am facing now is that when I checkout files from Subversion system, it doesn't show subversion file status on checked out file on network folder. If I do the same thing on local computer then it does show the subversion file status.

Doesn't anyone faced this kind of behaviour before? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Any help is appriciated

Comment: Are you using TortoiseSVN in Explorer or the command-line client? Subversion working copy state is just files, so it ought to work identically unless e.g. Tortoise doesn't handle networked shared in case there's a performance problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the icon overlays of TortoiseSVN:
those are disabled on network shares by default. But you can enable them again if you really, really have to: `Settings Dialog->Icon Overlays->Drive Types` - check the `"Network drives"` box.

But remember, there's a reason why this is disabled by default.

Comment: It works so a very big thank you but you can you explain the reason why it is disable on Network Drives

Comment: it's unreliable, it's slow, the status cache will be out-of-date most of the time, ...
basically: don't do it.